# Multiple Databases in Ado.net Entity framework for Mysql Provider

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, ado.net-entity-data-model

I want to have access to 2 different databases in Ado.net Entity framework. I created one .edmx file in  project, how can i access two different database in single .edmx file  Database provider is MySQL.

Regards,
venkateswararao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are two databases are same or different?

If same than you can use one emdx against both, you just have to create 2 dabase context objects with 2 different connection strings.

If they are different than you have to create 2 different emdx files.

Comment: they are different Databatabases I haver created two edmx files and i have resolve the issue thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. You must have separate EDMX file (and context) for each database. There are some ugly workarounds like exposing tables from second database via views in the first database (so EDMX talks only to the first database) but that brings other problems because views are read only in EF unless you create CUD stored procedures for every table exposed as a view.

Comment: Thank you very much for spending your valuable time to give Resolve my issue

Answer (score 0):

Preparing an Entity Framework model for multi provider support

Look To This [Go To Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/309858/Preparing-an-Entity-Framework-model-for-multi-pr)